# How to throw and get value in others page using air and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, air

i have a problem with my project. I want to build application using air and jquery. I get some records from database and displayed on Page_A . Then Every record in page A, have a link to Page_B that refers detail of record. But i don't know how to throw a value of every record in Page_A and get in Page_B.

Could somebody's help??

Regards

Comment: @what about querystring ?? or session ??or application variables,

Comment: @gov I still don't understand how to use querystring, session and app variable .. u sure they are supported by air? coz i still use html, jquery and adobeair. no server anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sthepen normally you should take the unique identifier from that link and make a call to database on page b again.

That unique identifier you can pass as a query string or so to the second page

```
<a href="pageb.aspx?employeeid=1"> </a> // i gave .aspx as a example
```

in page b , take that id and execute server side code